# Encrypt/decrypt string n JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric, node-crypto

I have a string, length of which is `0 <=  X <= 26`;

I need `encrypt` function which will encrypt this string to get X-character-length string: `encrypt("My String", "Passphrase", xLengthOutput)` -> `"01234567890123456789012345"`;

I also need `decrypt` function, which will take X-character-length string and output my original string `decrypt("01234567890123456789012345", "Passphrase")` -> `"My String"`;

NOTE: it's not a compression, original string is always smaller than or equal to encrypted result.

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for is a simple padding.

Comment: Modern encryption modes need Nonce/IV to be secure ( i.e. have at least Ind-CPA). The IV increases the size. In addition, block cipher in CBC mode requires padding that can increase the ciphertext size with block length.  The stream cipher like AES-CTR or ChaCha20 doesn't need padding, however, you still need to live the IV. If you want to keep formatting you need to use Format Preserving Encryption ( there you will still IV). So, what is your security model so that you may use or not  AES-CTR or ChaCha20 with fixed IVs?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) `Crypto.subtle` which returns a SubtleCrypto object providing access to common cryptographic primitives, like hashing, signing, encryption, or decryption.

Then you can use every method in [`SubtleCryptography`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) such as `encrypt` and `decrypt`.

Comment: Thanks Lior, I found some libraries which let me encrypt/decrypt, but I'm having trouble finding one, which lets you set encryption output length.

Comment: I'm afraid that controlling the output length is not quite feasible. You could encrypt using a one time pad key using XOR over the data which will give you the same output length, but it is quite hard to get it right security wise.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following function to encrypt and decrypt a string via javascript , it is simple one , for advanced version please use crypto API.

```
var encrypt = function(str, key) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var charCode = (str.charCodeAt(i) + key) % 256;
    result += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }
  return result;
}

var decrypt = function(str, key) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var charCode = (str.charCodeAt(i) - key + 256) % 256;
    result += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `xor` encryption. it's very simple. my code is working fine

```js
function encrypt(text, key){
    return [...text].map((x, i) => 
    (x.codePointAt() ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length) % 255)
     .toString(16)
     .padStart(2,"0")
   ).join('')
}
function decrypt(text, key){
    return String.fromCharCode(...text.match(/.{1,2}/g)
     .map((e,i) => 
       parseInt(e, 16) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length) % 255)
     )
}
let enc = encrypt("My String", "Passphrase")
let dec = decrypt(enc, "Passphrase")

console.log(enc) // 1d185320041a1b0f14
console.log(dec) // My String
```

Comment: It's very simple, and very insecure.

Comment: lol. there are no high rated answers. encrypt with `crypto` too many `loop` codes. takes up a lot of memory

Comment: If you want a fast algorithm, use the identity function. It takes 0 memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the below code is for demonstration purposes only and more complex encryption algorithms and more secure key management schemes should be used in real-world applications. In addition, since the Crypto API needs to run in HTTPS or local environment, the above code cannot run in a normal HTTP environment.

```
// Encryption function
function encrypt(str, key) {
  // Convert the key to a byte array
  var keyBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(key);

  // Convert the plaintext to a byte array
  var textBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);

  // Generate an AES key using the Crypto API
  crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", keyBytes, "AES-CBC", false, ["encrypt"]).then(function(key) {
    // Encrypt using AES algorithm
    crypto.subtle.encrypt({ name: "AES-CBC", iv: new Uint8Array(16) }, key, textBytes).then(function(encryptedBytes) {
      // Convert the encrypted byte array to a Base64 string
      var encryptedBase64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(encryptedBytes)));
      console.log("Encrypted string: ", encryptedBase64);
    });
  });
}

// Decryption function
function decrypt(encryptedBase64, key) {
  // Convert the key to a byte array
  var keyBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(key);

  // Convert the Base64 string to a byte array
  var encryptedBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(encryptedBase64).split("").map(function(c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); }));

  // Generate an AES key using the Crypto API
  crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", keyBytes, "AES-CBC", false, ["decrypt"]).then(function(key) {
    // Decrypt using AES algorithm
    crypto.subtle.decrypt({ name: "AES-CBC", iv: new Uint8Array(16) }, key, encryptedBytes).then(function(decryptedBytes) {
      // Convert the decrypted byte array to a string
      var decryptedText = new TextDecoder().decode(decryptedBytes);
      console.log("Decrypted string: ", decryptedText);
    });
  });
}

// Example code
var key = "MySecretKey12345"; // Key, can be any string of any length
var plaintext = "Hello World!"; // String to be encrypted

encrypt(plaintext, key);

var ciphertext = "q3Hx4zA4PTGZf41zZSSbEg=="; // Encrypted string, can be obtained from the encrypt function
decrypt(ciphertext, key);
```