# Caesar cipher - both ways, in one line (?)

Tags: javascript

tried to create a function that does caesar cipher (alphabet shift by `key` value). Wanted to do it in least lines possible (one line?). Was able to create a function:

```
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('')
let regExp = /[a-zA-Z]/;

function cypher(input, key){
    return input.split('').map((a) => (regExp.test(a)) ? alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(a) + key) % alphabet.length] : a).join('')
}
```

then I figured out that I can use the same function to decipher the code, except with reversed alphabet

```
const alphabetReverse = alphabet.reverse();

function decypher(input, key){
    return input.split('').map((a) => (regExp.test(a)) ? alphabetReverse[(alphabetReverse.indexOf(a) + key) % alphabetReverse.length] : a).join('')

}
```

then, I tried to do function that does both (if key < 0 it decyphers):

```
function cypher(input, key){
    let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(''); // 26 long, 0 to 25
    if(key < 0){
        alphabet = alphabet.reverse();
        key = -key;
    }
    return input.split('').map((a) => (regExp.test(a)) ? alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(a) + key) % alphabet.length] : a).join('')
}
```

I cant figure out a way to do both-ways function in an elegant way like just one-way.
(Sorry if i'm missing something, this is more of an learning question, I'm really new to programming, like 2-3 weeks.

Tried creating both-ways function in one line, couldnt do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reversing the alphabet conditionally, make use of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) (e.g. shifting backward 10 times is equal to shifting forward 16 times).

```js
const regExp = /[a-z]/i;
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
function cypher(input, key){
    return [...input].map(a => regExp.test(a) ? 
      alphabet[((alphabet.indexOf(a) + key) % alphabet.length + alphabet.length) 
        % alphabet.length] : a).join('');
}
console.log(cypher('test', 2));
console.log(cypher('vguv', -2));
console.log(cypher('xyz', 10));
console.log(cypher('hij', -10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like `ROT13` 
https://hellodevworld.com/365-days-of-coding/rot13-cipher-javascript-solution
or you can use `XOR` encryption string with key like: 
[Encrypt/decrypt string n JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73593867/encrypt-decrypt-string-n-javascript/76207040#76207040)